# clickedButtonAtIndex in appdelegate is not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, self, uiapplicationdelegate

I am calling UIAlert with 2 buttons "Cancel" and "OK" in MyapplicationAppDelegate.m file , the alert is called but on tap of "Cancel" or "OK" button

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

method is not called.

I have added UIAlertViewDelegate in the MyapplicationAppDelegate.h file as below

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h
@interface MyapplicationAppDelegate: NSObject UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate
{
..
}
```

I want to know what else is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure whether its your typo while posting the question but you should call the delegate within <.. , .. >

```
@interface MyapplicationAppDelegate: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate> { .. }
```

Here is sample code for UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""message:@"Your message goes here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myAlertView show];
    [myAlertView release];
```

**I am not sure myAlertView.delgate = self is the right method but i do set delegate with initWithTitle**

Comment: same as mentioned in your answer, but let me check once again.

Answer (score 2):

For me,

```
#define appDelegate ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                             message:@"Say Yes or NO?" delegate:appDelegate 
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    alertView.tag = 1;
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
```

do the trick!

Now its going into, `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;` in AppDelegate file without adding,

```
@interface MyapplicationAppDelegate: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate> { .. }
```